# Neo4J: Execute SET/CREATE Cypher Query embedded in a Java process

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to execute cypher queries within a Java process ([link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html)).

This worked fine for all queries like `MATCH xyz RETURN n`, but whenever I want to execute and write execute an operation like `CREATE` or `SET`, an exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: The given query is not supported at the moment in the selected cost-based planner
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException.asUserException(QueryExecutionKernelException.java:35)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.execute(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:970)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.execute(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:957)
at MainClass.embTestQuery(MainClass.java:85)
at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:28)
```

Code fragment:

```
    matchingQuery = "CREATE (n:testnode) RETURN n";
    try ( Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();
              Result result = 
                      db.execute( matchingQuery ))
        {
            while ( result.hasNext() )
            {
                Map<String,Object> row = result.next();
                for ( Entry<String,Object> column : row.entrySet() )
                {
                    rows += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
                }
                rows += "\n";
            }
        }
    System.out.println(rows);
```

Referenced Libraries:

- neo4j-consistency-check-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-csv-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-cypher-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.4.jar
- neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.4.jar
- neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.8.jar
- neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-graph-algo-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-graph-matching-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-import-tool-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-io-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-jmx-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-kernel-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-primitive-collections-2.2.5.jar
- lucene-core-3.6.2.jar
- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar
- neo4j-shell-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-udc-2.2.5.jar
- neo4j-unsafe-2.2.5.jar

Comment: Can you please share your piece of code? Showing us what you've tried

Comment: What dependencies (jars) does your code use?

Comment: added ref lib and code fragment

Comment: GraphDatabaseSettings.read_only is already set to false

Comment: Try to change your cypher planner : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html#config_dbms.cypher.planner

Comment: @Supamiu that worked, thank you

Comment: @aschi I will explain the problem with a real answer, a comment is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from your cypher planner, in [Neo4j's Documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-are-queries-executed.html) you can find out how cypher queries are executed.

The above sentence is showing your problem exactly:

> By default, Neo4j 2.2 will use the cost planner for some queries, but not all. You can force it to use a specific planner by using the query.planner.version configuration setting (see dbms.cypher.planner), or by prepending your query with CYPHER planner=cost or CYPHER planner=rule. Neo4j might still not use the planner you selected — not all queries are solvable by the cost planner at this point. Note that using PLANNER COST or PLANNER RULE in order to switch between planners has been deprecated and will stop working in future versions.

#### The Fix

To fix this, you can simply change, in your database configuration file, your cypher planner (see [dbms.cypher.planner documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html#config_dbms.cypher.planner) for a guide).

Comment: We confirmed that this issue can be reproduced by setting the database config "dbms.cypher.planner" to "COST". So it is likely that this is what was done, and it is best to leave this config unset (allowing the database to choose the best planner for the job), or setting this per query as described by Supamiu.